# Ruby on Rails - foreign key mismatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to use a string primary key for one model which acts as the foreign key for another model. Here are the two model definitions:

```rb
class Board < ApplicationRecord
  self.primary_key = :name
  has_many :topics, primary_key: :name
end

class Topic < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :board, primary_key: :name
end
```

And here is the corresponding database migration:

```rb
class CreateBoards < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :boards, id: :string, primary_key: :name do |t|
      t.timestamps
    end
    create_table :topics do |t|
      t.belongs_to :board, foreign_key: true, type: :string
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I can create a Board object fine with `b = Board.create(name: "test")`, and I can initialize a Topic object with `t = b.topics.new`, but I cannot save it, as it results in this error:

```
irb(main):002:0> t = b.topics.new
=> #<Topic:0x0000558d9e1ddea0 id: nil, board_id: "test", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):003:0> t.save
  TRANSACTION (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  Topic Create (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO "topics" ("board_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["board_id", "test"], ["created_at", "2023-08-01 09:57:21.876835"], ["updated_at", "2023-08-01 09:57:21.876835"]]
  TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
/var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.6.3-x86_64-linux/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:152:in `initialize': SQLite3::SQLException: foreign key mismatch - "topics" referencing "boards" (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
/var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.6.3-x86_64-linux/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:152:in `initialize': foreign key mismatch - "topics" referencing "boards" (SQLite3::SQLException)
```

Despite rails complaining, I can use the command `INSERT INTO "topics" ("board_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ("test", "2023-08-01 09:57:21.876835", "2023-08-01 09:57:21.876835");` in the database console just fine. I can even retrieve the Topic item in the rails console and save it.

**Edit**: I managed to fix this right before seeing a reply that would have been very helpful. After switching to Postgres, the issue of the incorrect column reference became more clear. The solution I came upon was to supply a hash object to the `:foreign_key` option in the database migration:

```rb
t.belongs_to :board, foreign_key: {primary_key: :name}, type: :string
```

Everything works as expected now. I would like to note that no where in the [Rails documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_reference) does it say that a hash can be supplied to the foreign key option (for this method); is this a recurring theme in the documentation?

Comment: Nice, well done. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If in your sqlite console, if you do a `.schema topics` you'll see that the foreign key points at `boards(id)`...  You'll also see that you can insert ANY `board_id` value into `topics`, the constraint isn't doing anything because sqlite.

You'll also see that if you try to create the same foreign key in a proper relational DB then you'll get an error about referencing a non-existent `boards.id` column.

<del>AFAIK, Rails doesn't support this arrangement, ie. having a foreign key pointing to any field in the other relation besides `id`. There'd have to be some syntax for the `foreign_key` option like: `foreign_key: { to_column: "name" }`</del>

#### Update - from OP

You need to pass an option hash to the `foreign_key` option like: `foreign_key: { primary_key: :name }`